Time from event to event in days in long-format dataset with R tidyverse
Suppose I have the following dataset in long format storing repeated measurements in several individuals.

obs_id identifies the individual.
time is an integer identifying consecutive measurements (1, 2, or 3).
date stores the date of the measurement for measurements 1 or 2, if available.
date_3, for reasons pertaining to data collection, stores separately the date of measurement 3, if available.

Here is a simple version with just three individuals.
  library(tidyverse)
  library(lubridate)
  sample_data <- tribble(
    ~obs_id, ~time, ~date, ~date_3,    
    "a", 1, ymd("2017-10-28"), NA_Date_,
    "a", 2, ymd("2017-11-09"), NA_Date_,
    "a", 3, NA_Date_, ymd("2017-11-12"), 
    "b", 1, ymd("2017-10-28"), NA_Date_,
    "b", 2, ymd("2017-11-09"), NA_Date_,
    "b", 3, NA_Date_, NA_Date_,    
    "c", 1, ymd("2017-10-05"), NA_Date_,
    "c", 3, NA_Date_, ymd("2017-10-29"),
 )

Now, we need to create, for each measurement, a variable that stores, for individuals with the measurement 2, in each row the number of days from the date of measurement 2 to the row's date (which is, as I wrote, stored in date for times 1 and 2, in date_3 only for time 3). For individuals with no measurement 2 at all, it is simply missing.
The expected result would be the following:
  expected_result <- tribble(
    ~obs_id, ~time, ~date, ~date_3, ~days_2_to_time,
    "a", 1, ymd("2017-10-28"), NA_Date_, -12, 
    "a", 2, ymd("2017-11-09"), NA_Date_, 0, 
    "a", 3, NA_Date_, ymd("2017-11-12"), 3,
    "b", 1, ymd("2017-10-28"), NA_Date_, -12, 
    "b", 2, ymd("2017-11-09"), NA_Date_, 0,
    "b", 3, NA_Date_, NA_Date_, NA_integer_,
    "c", 1, ymd("2017-10-05"), NA_Date_, NA_integer_,
    "c", 3, NA_Date_, ymd("2017-10-29"), NA_integer_
 )

I tried with the following, but it does not work and I do not understand why:
  sample_data <- sample_data |> 
    group_by(obs_id) |> 
    mutate(
      days_2_to_time = case_when(
        2 %in% time & time != 3 ~ as.duration(date[time == 2] %--% date)/ddays(1),
        2 %in% time & time == 3 ~ as.duration(date[time == 2] %--% date_3)/ddays(1),
        ! 2 %in% time ~ NA_integer_
      )
    ) |> 
    ungroup()

The error message
Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `days_2_to_time = case_when(...)`.
ℹ In group 3: `obs_id = "c"`.
Caused by error in `case_when()`:
! Can't recycle `..1 (left)` (size 2) to match `..1 (right)` (size 0).
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

explains that the problem is in the observation "c", the one without time 2, which should be easily handled by the condition ! 2 %in% time. I do not understand why the left-hand result is of size 2, because ! 2 %in% time should return a single TRUE. Note that the syntax works fine if one excludes observation "c", for instance with filter(obs_id != "c") before the call to mutate.
EDIT: I realise that my thinking mistake is that case_when operates row by row, and the condition ! 2 %in% time also does (I was thinking that it would operate on the whole vector time in each subset defined by obs_id). My question, then, becomes: how I test the condition ! 2 %in% time on the whole time column? The result by row should depend on the existence of the row with time == 2.

Join the data frame with a subset of itself which only contains the time==2 rows, then do the calculations:
sample_data %>%
  left_join(transmute(filter(sample_data, time==2), obs_id, date2 = date), by = c("obs_id")) %>%
  mutate(
    combined_date = coalesce(date, date_3),
    days_2_to_time = (combined_date - date2)/ddays(1)
  ) %>%
  select(-date2, -combined_date)


I think this is a simpler solution, it works to reproduce your expected_result tribble but feel free to comment and I can work on it further.
sample_data %>% 
  left_join(
    y = sample_data %>% 
      filter(time == 2) %>% 
      select(obs_id, date_2 = date)
    ,by = c("obs_id" = "obs_id")
  ) %>% 
  mutate(
    days_2_to_time = as.integer(
      difftime(
        if_else(is.na(date), date_3, date), 
        date_2, 
        units = "days"
      )
    )
  ) %>% 
  select(-date_2)

# A tibble: 8 × 5
  obs_id  time date       date_3     days_2_to_time
  <chr>  <dbl> <date>     <date>              <int>
1 a          1 2017-10-28 NA                    -12
2 a          2 2017-11-09 NA                      0
3 a          3 NA         2017-11-12              3
4 b          1 2017-10-28 NA                    -12
5 b          2 2017-11-09 NA                      0
6 b          3 NA         NA                     NA
7 c          1 2017-10-05 NA                     NA
8 c          3 NA         2017-10-29             NA

I didn't use lubridate, and only used dplyr. We are first interested in date when second measurement was taken for each obs_id, so we filter for time == 2. The resultant tibble is then left_joined with the original, creating a new column called time_2.
We then take the time difference between date column or date_3 column (whichever exists) and our new column time_2.
